# How to combine macros in NMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, nmake

I am trying to combine macro in NMake? I start like this.

`nmake -f C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\build.makefile TEST`

But the output is

`fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '$' in macro
 Stop.`

Instead of `-03`

```
FLAGS_PLATFORM     = %PLATFORM%
FLAGS_BUILD_TYPE   = %BUILD_TYPE%

FLAGS_X86_RELEASE  = -O3
FLAGS_X86_DEBUG    = -O3

FLAGS_X64_RELEASE  = -O3
FLAGS_X64_DEBUG    = -O3

FLAGS_COMPILER_X86 = compiler.exe
FLAGS_COMPILER_X64 = compiler.exe

FLAGS  = $(FLAGS_$(FLAGS_PLATFORM)_$(FLAGS_BUILD_TYPE))

TEST:
     echo "$(FLAGS)"
```

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses in your FLAGS line.  You might be able to use something like: `FLAGS = $(FLAGS_$(FLAGS_PLATFORM)_$(FLAGS_BUILD_TYPE))`, but that may well not be allowed. (Some versions of `make` may accept it, such as GNU `make`; many others will not.  I don't know where NMake falls.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried it with GNU `make` but I get just "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU `make` (3.81, running on Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite), this makefile (`example.mk`) works:

```
FLAGS_PLATFORM     = X86
FLAGS_BUILD_TYPE   = DEBUG

FLAGS_X86_RELEASE  = -m32 -O3
FLAGS_X86_DEBUG    = -m32 -g

FLAGS_X64_RELEASE  = -m64 -O3
FLAGS_X64_DEBUG    = -m64 -g

FLAGS = $(FLAGS_$(FLAGS_PLATFORM)_$(FLAGS_BUILD_TYPE))

test:
        @echo "$(FLAGS)"
```

For example:

```
$ make -f example.mk
-m32 -g
$ make -f example.mk FLAGS_PLATFORM=X64 FLAGS_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
-m64 -O3
$ make -f example.mk FLAGS_PLATFORM=X64 
-m64 -g
$ make -f example.mk FLAGS_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
-m32 -O3
$ make -f example.mk FLAGS_PLATFORM=X86 FLAGS_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
-m32 -g
$
```

You can mix'n'match defaults built into the `makefile` with command-line overrides.  If you chose to use environment variables, on Unix you'd use `$(PLATFORM)` rather than `%PLATFORM%` (and `$(BUILD_TYPE)` rather than `%BUILD_TYPE%`) in the `makefile`; `make` imports all the environment variables (except `SHELL`) and makes them available as macros.

Note that the `makefile` has no trailing comments after the FLAGS_PLATFORM and FLAGS_BUILD_TYPE macros; those broke the efforts to build a variable name (unless you use the command-line overrides).

Whether this works with GNU `make` on Windows, or with NMake (on Windows) is beyond my ken.